# Extracting a string from a JSON object

Tags: java, android, wcf, json

I have some code not shown here that pulls an `IMEI` number in `JSON` format from a database via a WCF and I now have it in the following format which I can display,

```
{"getIMEIResult":"268003456767887"}
```

Via,

```
jsonResponse = new JSONObject(new String(buffer));              
IMEICheckResponse = jsonResponse.toString();
```

And then Toast IMEICheckResponse to get

`{"getIMEIResult":"268003456767887"}.`

How do I extract 268003456767887 from the JSON object and put it into the IMEICheckResponse string?

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its very simple,

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(your_json_response_string);
String IMEICheckResponse  = object.getString("getIMEIResult");
Log.d("output", IMEICheckResponse);
```

Comment: Simple when you know how…lol. Funny how I’ve gotten this far with an SQL Server database, an MVC3 administration backend where I can CRUD phone and user details and an Android app that communicates via a WCF to and fro, and I needed help with this…lol thanks Lalit, you are a champ!